# Safari can't get HEROKU's cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, safari

I am sorry that I am not able to provide much info because I totally have no idea about this weird problem.

I have a fb canvas app which is written by rails 3.2.2 .

There is not any problem on my local machine (Mac OS X 10.7.4).

When I deploy it to heroku, it is fine with chrome and firefox. However, when I use Safari to browse it, Safari can't get any cookie from heroku. (it shows "This site has no cookies" in developer tool, but it works well on my local machine.)

I have googled this problem, and I get something like [this](http://viget.com/extend/rails-sessions-not-working-with-safari-a-solution) and [this](http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/showthread.php?t=2037), but I don't think these are the case of mine.

any suggestion?

If you need any specific info about my code to solve this problem, please let me know.

I will appreciate it very very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out that it's a problem of safari's security setting.

As fb canvas gets heroku's content through iframe, there may be security issues. If we donwgrade the 'Block cookies' of safari's privacy settings from 'From third parties and advertisers'(default) to 'Never', everything works well![image: setting example]

However, I don't think asking users to downgrade their security settings is a good idea. I am wondering whether there is a solution to avoid this restriction in safari.

please let me know if you have any idea. many thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Brian, I have the same problem and you identified it for me. Now...the solution? I am also putting a heroku app in a facebook canvas. But I feel like I missing something here. There must be thousands of people using facebook-->heroku. Why is it just us two? I rolled my own minimal authentication, based on the docs. Did you? Maybe devise et al have solved this problem.

Comment: I still don't have ideal solution. I gave up to be compatible with safari. As I mentioned in the question, this issue does not exist in Chrome and Firefox, and I used a gem to avoid this restriction in IE (https://github.com/grosser/ie_iframe_cookies). I think my fb app could serve most users with being compatible with these 3 browsers.
However, I am still wondering whether there is a good solution.